# javascript ignores if statement with equation element greater than 1?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using this bit of code to make a parallax effect for a div background on the site http://ovariancancer.com.au/#acts

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    //gets height
    var pContainerHeight = $('#heightid').outerHeight(true);
    console.log(pContainerHeight);
    //gives div that height
    $('.kujoimgpos').css({'height' : pContainerHeight + 'px'});

    $(window).scroll(function(){

        var scrollStart = $('#imgstart').offset().top;

        console.log(scrollStart);

        var wScroll = $(this).scrollTop();

        console.log(wScroll);

        var scrollBottom = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

        console.log(scrollBottom);

        if (scrollBottom => scrollStart) {

        $('.kujoimgpos').css({
              'background-position' : '0 -'+(200 + ((wScroll - scrollStart) *0.2)) +'px'
        });
      }
    });

});
```

what it does is grab the distance between the div and the top of the page and makes the div background image start moving upwards at 20% or whatever value I choose. It uses jqueries .scrollTop to start the equation which changes the background-position of the div with an equation like this:

```
$('.kujoimgpos').css({
              'background-position' : '0 -'+(200 + ((wScroll - scrollStart) *.2)) +'px'
        });
```

Now as I was testing this I was using *.2 because I wanted a slow moving image. But I just wanted to see what it looked like at say 2 or 3 times the speed you're scrolling. So I changed it to 2, and once you do that, it only starts scrolling once the top of the div hits the top of the page, which makes senses because of the if statement where we check if scrollTop is bigger than offset().top, only after doing this did I realise that I shouldn't be using offset().top because I want the scrolling to start when the image first touches the bottom of the page, okay well change scrollTop to ScrollBottom ..haha, well scrollBottom would use the distance from the actual bottom of the document which we don't want so we make a new var called scrollBottom `var scrollBottom = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();`and use that in our if statement but still use wScroll in our background-position equation because it's just a way to add (1 * (whatever % you want))px to the image background position once we get to that position on the screen.

So it seems that by changing the value which we're controlling the image scroll speed with it's affecting the start time of the scroll too. Any ideas?

Here's all the related html and css too:

```
<section id="acts" class="acts">
<div class="container-fluid" >
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-2 kujopad" id="heightid">
                <h1>The Kujo Kings</h1>
                <p>

                    Known for their Ska/Punk anthems and high energy packed out shows, this 20 something band has built a strong Australian-wide following since forming in 2010.  The six-piece band are dedicated to entertaining fans with their catchy and humorous tunes, with dangerous amounts of energy, dancing, costumes and gratuitous fun being a consistent feature of their shows, the Kujo Kings are an act not to be missed!

                    </p>
        </div>
        <div id="imgstart" class="col-sm-4 kujoimgpos">
        <! the image is here >
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</section>
```

hm

```
.kujoimgpos {
    margin-left: 150px;
    background-image: url('/img/kujokings.jpg');
    background-size: auto 700px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: A greater-or-equal comparison is done with `>=` not `=>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok so I fixed the issue by just changing the if statement from what it was, to this:

```
if (wScroll >= scrollStart) {

        $('.kujoimgpos').css({
              'background-position' : '0 -'+(60 + ((wScroll - scrollStart) *.2)) +'px'
        });
      }
```

and actually changed the scrollStart var to minus the window height so everything matches up.

```
var scrollStart = $('#imgstart').offset().top - $(window).height();
```

Answer (score 0):

The "fat arrow" (`=>`) is an [ES 2015 function shorthand syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). Your `if` statement could be rewritten into the following:

```
if (function(scrollBottom) { return scrollStart }) {
  // ...
}
```

... which will, obviously, always evaluate to `true`, because all functions are basically objects.

As pointed out in other answers, if you want to do a "greater or equal than" comparison, you need to use `>=`.